# restart ros2 controller

Tags: gazebo, ros2, urdf, ros-humble, ros2-control

I am working on a 4 wheel ackermann steering car which is expected to respawn on the track once it moves out of the track.
I am able to respawn it successfully with "delete_entity" and "spawn_entity" service but the issue is after being respawned, I am unable to control the robot.
After printing the output of "ros2 topic list" I found out, earlier there were 5 topics related to the ackermann controller:

```
Topics before respawn:
/asc/controller_state
/asc/odometry
/asc/reference
/asc/tf_odometry
/asc/transition_event
```

and after respawn only 2 are left:

```
/asc/odometry    // For getting robot position data.  
/asc/reference   // For controlling the robot.
```

Now i think it would be better to restart controller after every respawn. Is there any way to restart the controller from other node?

#### Launch File:

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import launch_ros

from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('race_it'))
    
    #xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description', 'race_car.xacro')
    
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_path, 'config/rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config.toxml(), 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )
    
    
        
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher'
    )
    

    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', default_rviz_config_path],
    )

    
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
            launch_arguments={'world': "./src/race_it/worlds/track_4.world"}.items()
    )
    
    
    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=['-entity', '', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
        output='screen'
    )
    
    ackermann_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["asc"],
)

    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use sim time if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher,
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        rviz_node,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
        ackermann_spawner
    ])
```

Any other suggestions like to directly move the robot to the respawn location instead of deleting and spawning it again thus eliminating the need of controller restart are also welcome(Although i am unable to do this as "/gazebo_msgs/srv/SetModelState" service is not available for calling).

Thankyou.

Comment: can you check for available services of this node. It seems like a lifecycle based implementation. The topic **/node_name/transition_event** becomes available when a node has lifecycle implementation. If it has a lifecycle implementation then better way would be to use lifecycle services for stoping/starting the controller.

Comment: I suppose that delete entity and spawn_entity would delete and recreate also the ros2_control node, which manages the lifecycle of your controller. (not sure though)
Can you analyze the output of the ros2_control_node during delete/spawn, what does it report?

Comment: @ChristophFroehlich any idea how to do that?

Comment: You should see something like 

    `[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1710317253.237352851] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'forward_position_controller'
    [gzserver-1] [INFO] [1710317253.254926350] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'forward_position_controller'
    [gzserver-1] [INFO] [1710317253.539591475] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this now with

```
ros2 launch gazebo_ros2_control_demos diff_drive.launch.py
ros2 service call /delete_entity gazebo_msgs/srv/DeleteEntity "{name: diffbot}" 
ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -topic /robot_description -entity diffbot2
```

Then you see in the terminal that gazebo_ros2_control and the controller_manager will be loaded again, but the controllers are not spawned (check with `ros2 control list_controllers`). See `ackermann_spawner` from your launch file, or use [ros2 control load_controller](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/ros2controlcli/doc/userdoc.html)